# Capitalization of "biomedical"

Tags: capitalization

I work at a company with the word "biomedical" in its name. Sometimes I see it capitalized in CamelCase, like a programmer would write it ("BioMedical"), and sometimes as one word ("Biomedical"). The second capitalization looks better to me, but I'm not sure. I've also seen the word written out as "bio-medical".

There seem to be too many options. **Can anyone enlighten me on the proper capitalization?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is *biomedical* and has been since at least 1921. At the start of a sentence, or in a title, it would be capitalised as *Biomedical*.

If some company chooses to use *BioMedical* as part of a brand, that's their business. It doesn't change the word as generally used, just as *CinemaScope* doesn't change the words *cinema* or *scope* as generally used.

The hyphenated *bio-medical* is also used, and if capitalised would be *Bio-medical* at the start of a sentence, but *Bio-Medical* in title-case.

At this stage though, the closed compound *biomedical* is well-enough attested that one is safer using that; hyphenating it my seem old-fashioned, bordering on twee.

Strike a red pen through *BioMedical* if it's not a brand. Strike a red pen through the hyphen of *bio-medical* only if you're enforcing a style-guide, as it isn't actually incorrect.

Comment: "Twee" is a British term, probably not understood in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: companies can do what they want with their names.

The term *[biomedical](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/biomedical)* is a recognized term aside from the company name. As such, standard capitalization would usually apply and, where a capital was needed, it would be *Biomedical*.

Often company names and brand names use nonstandard capitalization, especially when the term used is a neologism or fanciful term, such as *FedEx*.

This internal capitalization is much less common when the term is a recognized word, unless the company is trying to draw attention to the latter portion.

But your company can do whatever it wants, even *BiomedicaL* if it chooses. Check on, and follow company policy.